# where is "@strings/variable_name" stored while using it in .xml files

Tags: android, flutter, environment-variables

I was using the google maps api in my flutter project and it asked me to put my api key in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I went through an article to learn the correct way to add the api key to my file so that it stays out of version control.

However I am curious about the following:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"
/>
```

Where is the value of `@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` coming from? Where is it stored?

I know that I have a .env file that stores the api key but how does it get converted to `@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY`?

Comment: In one of the xml files in ../app/src/main/res/values ?

Comment: @blackapps android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Anything labeled @XXX comes from the values resource files.  @string would come from the string.xml file.  Please note that this is not a secured way to list the key, as it would put the key in your source code and thus in version control.  However you can replace this method with any more secure method you want-  you don't need to get the value from that file.

Comment: Can you point me to any article that implements it in a more secure way?

Comment: also as I am using flutter there is no strings.xml file (unless i'm not looking at the right place) that contains the api key. 
https://i.postimg.cc/MX2jhmDq/image.png